# How to split string with subtotal prefix

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group, subtotal

I want to split string

```
'something.somethingMore.evenMore[123].last'
```

to

```
['something',
'something.somethingMore',
'something.somethingMore.evenMore[123]',
'something.somethingMore.evenMore[123].last']
```

I can't figure out simple solution to split string by separator '.', but with preceding content of string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modern JS programming style would be something like

```
str                                             //take the input
    .split('.')                                 //and split it into array of segments,
    .map(                                       //which we map into a new array,
        function(segment, index, segments)      //where for each segment
            return segments.slice(0, index+1)   //we take the segments up to its index
                .join(".")                      //and put them back together with '.'
            ;
         }
    )
```

This takes advantage of the fact that the `Array#map` function passes not only the current value, but also its index and the entire input array. That allows us to easily use `slice` to get an array containing all the segments up to the current one.

Comment: Nice solution. Thanks. I tried matching with regex but no luck to do it universal.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't call my solution simple but:

```
function splitArrayIntoGoofyArray(val){
  var str =val.split("."), arr = [];
  for (var x = str.length; x >= 1; x--){
     var cnt = str.length - x;
     arr.push((cnt > 0) ? arr[cnt - 1] + "." + str[cnt] : str[cnt]);
  }
  return arr;
}
console.log(splitArrayIntoGoofyArray("aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd"));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7tav4sue/

Answer (score 2):

You could try matching instead of splitting,

```
> var s = 'something.somethingMore.evenMore[123].last';
undefined
> var regex = /(?=(^((([^.]*)\.[^.]*)\.[^.]*)\.[^.]*))/g;
undefined
> regex.exec(s)
[ '',
  'something.somethingMore.evenMore[123].last',
  'something.somethingMore.evenMore[123]',
  'something.somethingMore',
  'something',
  index: 0,
  input: 'something.somethingMore.evenMore[123].last' ]
```

To get the desired output,

```
> regex.exec(s).slice(1,5)
[ 'something.somethingMore.evenMore[123].last',
  'something.somethingMore.evenMore[123]',
  'something.somethingMore',
  'something' ]
```

Comment: Very clever, although I'm not quite sure how it works.

Comment: You dont need regex here. You could split and loop

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what is simple solution.
The easiest way to do it is to create first array with

```
var str = 'something.somethingMore.evenMore[123].last';
var arr = str.split('.');
```

And then fill new array with this data

```
var result = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var item = [];
    for (var j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
        item.push(arr[j]);
    }
    result.push(item.join('.'))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you'll need a loop :

while finding "." character, return in a list substring till new "." index. Use the last correct index found to start each search.